# Live Server in vscode doesn't open browser automatically

Tags: web, browser, vscode-extensions, liveserver

I'm using vscode and when i start live server it starts but the browser doesn't open automatically

the live server when it starts it should open the browser automatically but it doesn't

This The Project that i'm trying to start live server on it :

[image]

Live Server Settings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem by adding system32 path